# Asp.net core Web Api post request not working

Tags: c#, api, post, asp.net-core-webapi

I had a task to make Add method and then to use that method as an endpoint to make API call through my ASP.NET Core. Everything worked with Swagger UI but I was supposted to make my own frontend and I uninstalled Swagger and deleted everything Swagger related from configuration and I rewrote what I needed. Now I get error...

I expected to get a result but instead got the error message

This is my controller

```
namespace APIProject.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TextCalculatorController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public string Calculate(string input)
        {
            return new TextCalculator().Add(input);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the api call

```
 document.getElementById("calculator-form").addEventListener("submit", async function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const numbers = event.target.elements.numbers.value;

    try {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:44313/api/TextCalculator", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ numbers: numbers }),
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(response.statusText);
        }

        const result = await response.text();
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
    } catch (error) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = error.message;
    }
});
```

This is the method:

```
public class TextCalculator
{
    public string Add(string numbers)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(numbers))
        {
            return "0";
        }

        string[] numberStrings = numbers.Split(',');
        int[] numbersArray = new int[numberStrings.Length];
        List<int> negativeNumbers = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberStrings.Length; i++)
        {

            if (!int.TryParse(numberStrings[i], out numbersArray[i]))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Input must contain only digits.");
            }

            if (numbersArray[i] < 0)
            {
                negativeNumbers.Add(numbersArray[i]);
            }

            if (numberStrings[numberStrings.Length - 1].Length == 0)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Missing number in last position.");
            }
        }

        if (negativeNumbers.Count > 0)
        {
            string negativeNumbersList = string.Join(", ", negativeNumbers);
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Negative numbers not allowed: " + negativeNumbersList);
        }

        int result = 0;
        foreach (int number in numbersArray)
        {
            result += number;
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }
}
```

Can problem be found in this json file???

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:10089",
      "sslPort": 44313
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "UI/index.html",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "APIProject": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "UI/index.html",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you share us what exact error you are getting? Have you checked the console or log in browser?

Comment: In addition, could you please share deatils of `TextCalculator().Add(input)`?

Comment: The connection was reset. This is the error i get in the browser.

Comment: I added my method in the question and i've tried your solution but they didn't work. Anyway, thank you for your time.

Comment: How you you tried? What exactly didn't work? Are you getting any error on browser? Could you share your updated code snippet? Didn't work means it doesn't hit your controller or your haven't get response?

Comment: "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" is the error in the browser. I don't think the controller is the problem because when i had Swagger UI i had the controller too and everything worked fine, but when i erased Swagger and made my own UI than i get "failed to fetch" instead of the result

Comment: You are not sending your request from your frontend code accordingly. As I told you earlier, if you want to keep your controller as it is than change UI code and send request in query string like `const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5094/api/TextCalculator?input=" + numbers` and get rid of  `body: JSON.stringify({ numbers: numbers }),` But if  you want to keep your UI code as it is than modify your controller code. Your are not trying the solution in correct way.

Comment: Another issue could be in browser, please clear your Cache in browser setting. Delete All cookie One By One.

Comment: Tried everything. I think that maybe the problem is not in the code but in connection or port

Comment: I prrety sure and confident code snippet are file but other issue. Have you tried with some other port? Would be great if you include few trace log from network with details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I had a task to make Add method and then to use that method as an
> endpoint to make API call through my ASP.NET Core. Everything worked
> with Swagger UI but I was supposted to make my own frontend and I
> uninstalled Swagger and deleted everything Swagger related from
> configuration and I rewrote what I needed. Now I get error

Well, your getting error from controller is pretty obvious and logical because you are sending your request using  request body: whilst your controller doesn't know about it at all and expecting paramter in querystring  as `string input`.

Thus, to resolve your issue, you have two options. Either send request from your UI using query string or update your controller in a way so that, It can accept request body.

**If you want to change Javascript:**

In this scenario, your controller code snippet would be same at the same time, you need following modification on your fetch request function in Javascript:

```
const numbers = "100";
            const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5094/api/TextCalculator?input=" + numbers, {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
               
            });
console.log("Rquest Submitted");
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(response.statusText);
            }

            const result = await response.text();

            console.log(result);
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
```

**Note:**  As you can notice, if you want to send request as per your controller defination, you ought to send reqeust as query string for that is [api/TextCalculator?input=" + numbers](https://api/TextCalculator?input=%22%20%20%20numbers) and body wouldn't require to send anymore.

Output:

[image]

**If you want to Modify Controller As Per [FromBody] :**

If you want to keep your Javascript unchanged in that scenario, you have to modify your controller Calculate action in a way so that, it can accept [FromBody] request.

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public string Calculate([FromBody] FromBodyRequestModel model)
        {
            return new TextCalculator().Add(model.input);
        }
```

Model:

```
 public class FromBodyRequestModel
    {
        public string input { get; set; }
    }
```

**Note:** What more is, If you want to update your controller action as per your UI code so you need to use [FromBody] in your controller action parameter and one additional request model which is FromBodyRequestModel in this context.

Output:

[image]

Comment: Mr. Kiron your answer was correct. After resolving my issue (i should have used HTTPS instead of HTTP since my port was ssl port) i noticed with debugging that code is not using the body, so i changed the JS code and everything worked right. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and glad to hear your issue has been resolved.